# User agent has incorrectly formatted header in .NET Core

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

We have a library compiled in .NET Standard 2.0, which has a WCF service. In order to add a custom header to requests to the web service we've implemented the code here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mohamedg/2012/12/13/adding-http-headers-to-wcf-calls/

When we reference this library in a .NET Framework app, we can make any calls to the web service that we want, and the correct results are returned just fine. However, in a .NET Core 2.0 app, the library often (but not always!) throws a `System.FormatException`, depending on the user agent we set.

Something like "Mozilla/4.0" will not throw the error, but "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)" will, **but only** in the Core app with the error message "The format of value '(compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)' is invalid.".

In short, here is the code (left out methods from the interface that have no implementation). Current user agent is hardcoded just for the sake of troubleshooting.

```
internal class ClientUserAgentMessage : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public ClientUserAgentMessage(string userAgent) { }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty property = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();

        //This is an example user agent that fails, and we would not expect it to.
        property.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)";
        request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, property);

        return null;
    }
}

internal class UserAgentEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public UserAgentEndpointBehavior() { }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new ClientUserAgentMessage());
    }
}
```

Code above is implemented in an application that references the Standard dll like so (leaving out client initialization details):

```
//SoapClient and related WCF code is generated from the web service via svcutil.exe
SoapClient client = new SoapClient(...);
client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new UserAgentEndpointBehavior());

//Call some web service functions...
//This succeeds in a .NET 4.7 app, 
//but blows up in a .NET Core 2.0 app due to the user agent being an "invalid format".
//client.Login();
```

Why is this a problem for only .NET Core, when the user-agent actually appears to be a valid format? It appears to complain where there is more that 1 /, parenthesis, colon, semicolon, space... Basically anything non-alphanumeric besides the first /, underscores, and decimals.

As requested, full stacktrace:

```
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser.ParseValue(String value, Object storeValue, Int32& index)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue.Parse(String input)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.PrepareMessageHeaders(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.<RequestAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.<RequestAsyncInternal>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.TaskHelpers.WaitForCompletionNoSpin[TResult](Task`1 task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(MethodCall methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, Object[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Reflection.DispatchProxyGenerator.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at generatedProxy_1.Login(LoginRequest )
   at MyServiceNamespace.SoapClient.ServiceNamespace.Soap.Login(LoginRequest request)
   at MyServiceNamespace.SoapClient.Login(String strUser, String strPass, String strKey)
   at MyLibraryNamespace.MyClass.Login(String sUser, String sPass, String sKey)
```

FWIW, you can set to headers other than "User-Agent" and everything is fine (or at least, I tried with "XTESTX" and no exception).

Comment: You replaced the spaces in the user agent with `+`.  Why?  [it isn't valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Comment: @Amy - Sorry, must have pasted the code mid-experiment. See updated code. Same error (slightly different message, portion before the first space gets broken out) whether spaces or pluses.

Comment: It probably helps to know where, exactly, it blows up (as in, the stack trace). WCF is a fairly new addition to the Core stack; this may well be a bug.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - See edit. Just replaced my app and service namespaces/classes with dummy values. We attempted to work through some of the wcf core code yesterday, but I'll admit, it's a bit over my head...

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a bug. Specifically, `PrepareMessageHeaders` should not be using `ProductInfoHeaderValue.Parse` to parse `User-Agent` values, as that class handles only parts -- a full `User-Agent` header is a collection of such values, as demonstrated in [`HttpRequestHeaders.UserAgent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.useragent). Overall, these classes are rather poorly designed (there is no public API for parsing full values that I can see); I don't blame the Core author for getting it wrong.

Comment: I believe the issue would be fixed by changing [this line](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/10ef8483a26611533eace9a9040ecf650c8d353e/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelFactory.cs#L1217) from `_httpRequestMessage.Headers.UserAgent.Add(ProductInfoHeaderValue.Parse(value));` to `_httpRequestMessage.Headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(value);`, but I'm not motivated enough to do the whole test/pull request dance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had opened an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2673) on GitHub on March 14th, 2018.

Looks like it was addressed and fixed that following May via this [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/pull/2857) and should no longer be an issue.

Comment: Have had the same issue yesterday under .NET 5 (though not with your header value).